# How do i get rid of IOS version "is partial: introduced in IOS X" warnings in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios11

So, i have some places where things are only available after a certain version. One example is some new NFC stuff i've introduced in my app:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NFCNDEFReaderSession *nfcSession;
```

I also have it in methods, where i get it even though i check for class availability, for example:

```
if ([NFCNDEFReaderSession class]){
```

my app works fine, but i get an xcode warning saying

```
NFCNDEFReaderSession is partial: introduced in iOS 11.0
```

I have looked around but haven't found a way to tell the compiler that it's fine and get rid of the warning.

Pointers much appreciated!

Comment: It is useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47443783/suppressing-is-partial-introduced-in-ios-in-parts-of-code

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Add NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(11.0) to the end of the method name. For example:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canHandleDropSession:(id<UIDropSession>)session NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(11.0) {

}
```

Method calls can be wrapped in the following to silence the new API warning

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {}
```

Comment: Thank you, this hit the spot! Forgot about this somehow :)

Answer (score 10):

You can silence specific warnings on parts of your code by adding Clang “pragmas” around it. In this case:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunguarded-availability"

// your code

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Documentation: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-via-pragmas

Answer (score 1):

To silence the warning, change the target's "Other warning flags" to either:

- -Wno-partial-availability
- -Wno-unguarded-availability

Answer (score 0):

You can also turn off `Unguarded availability` in the project settings. If you're using Cocoapods, it's now on by default in the `Pods` project.

[image]