# Suppressing "is partial: introduced in iOS" in parts of code

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, xcode8

My app is available also for iOS9...

when declaring however

```
- (UISwipeActionsConfiguration *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

i get warnings on `is partial: introduced in iOS 11.0+`, which doesn't make sence in this case, since the method wont be called prior to iOS11

i want to silence the warning for this part of code

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can flag the method with  `NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(11_0)` to indicate that it is only available on iOS 11 and suppress the warnings:

```
-(UISwipeActionsConfiguration *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(11_0)
```

Comment: awesome, that what i was looking for

Comment: great, that save my time @Paul